# Significato di "leggi" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Il signor Podestà*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> A metà si fermò, da dove aveva completa visuale della cascina dei Cora, laggiú, presso il ponticello sul rio secco affluente di Belbo, dirimpetto al mulino abbandonato. Di lassú però non poteva distinguere i dettagli – **leggi** presenze e movimenti dei familiari di Maria – quindi discese di un altro centinaio di scalini.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "leggi" in questo brano? Ho cercato i termini "leggio" e "legge" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato nessuna accezione che abbia senso in questo contesto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In questo caso *leggi* significa *cioè* o *vale a dire*. Il senso letterale è quello di un'esortazione a leggere *presenze e movimenti [...] di Maria* al posto di *dettagli*. Esempi più semplici di questa costruzione sono

> Il capo ha dato dei consigli - leggi ordini - all'interno
>
> Luigi negava sempre che la sua franchezza - leggi maleducazione - gli causasse problemi con le donne

Comment: Forse un prestito dal lessico filologico.

Comment: Si tratta dell'imperativo alla seconda persona singolare e quindi è informale?

Comment: @Charo Sì, si tratta dell'imperativo di seconda persona, ma non mi suona troppo informale. È più una frase fatta, per cui c'è un po' di resistenza al cambiare la coniugazione (per esempio io userei *leggi* anche parlando a più persone)

Comment: E non si usa "si legga" come espressione equivalente più formale? In spagnolo si usa "léase" con questo stesso significato.

Comment: @Charo *Si legga* è sicuramente accettabile. Non sono esattamente sicuro di quale sia la convenzione sociale qui

Comment: Ho trovato alcuni esempi di questo uso di "leggi" su Google Books: https://books.google.es/books?id=JWpXSrAEbG8C&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=%22leggi+collaborazione%22&source=bl&ots=9LZgB-Tkkc&sig=dgy37G-UR0XKxTXQ2f5-xFbGQdc&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjmp_X8t3dAhVEzhoKHbNZBA0Q6AEwBHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22leggi%20collaborazione%22&f=false, https://books.google.es/books?id=aWcgAQAAMAAJ&q=%22leggi+partiti%22&dq=%22leggi+partiti%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAk9m6893dAhVLz4UKHSoZBJMQ6AEILDAF.

Comment: Mi sembra davvero curioso che si usi la seconda persona singolare.